# data-toggle not working when nested elements are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, navbar, element

I have a navbar, when the notification bell is clicked, it should run this js function

```
    $('[data-toggle="slide-right"]').click(function ()
{
     $('.notification-feed').toggle("show");

});
```

it only opens .notification-feed when i small area that surrounds the bell is clicked

here's the html

```
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" data-toggle="slide-right">
                <li class="nav-item d-block active">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-bell">
                        <i class="bi bi-bell"></i><span class="badge badge-light" id="notificationCount"></span>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: In the HTML you have posted here there is no notification-feed class. Please add the whole HTML if you really want someone to help you. Also, I've created a small fiddle with only your code and it works fine. Probably you have something else that gets in the way of this code. Link to the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/807fzyqt/

Answer (score 0):

I added an id to the ul

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" data-toggle="slide-right" id="notification-bell">
```

then added css and a z-index to the id

```
#notification-bell {
z-index: 0;
}
```